# How to prod a SwiftUI view to update when a model class sub-property changes?

Tags: swiftui

I've created a trivial project to try to understand this better. Code below.

I have a source of data (`DataSource`) which contains a `@Published` array of `MyObject` items. `MyObject` contains a single string. Pushing a button on the UI causes one of the `MyObject` instances to update immediately, plus sets off a timer to update a second one a few seconds later.

If `MyObject` is a struct, everything works as I imagine it should. But if `MyObject` is a class, then the refresh doesn't fire.

My expectation is that changing a struct's value causes an altered instance to be placed in the array, setting off the chain of updates. However, if `MyObject` is a class then changing the string within a reference type leaves the same instance in the array. Array doesn't realise there has been a change so doesn't mention this to my `DataSource`. No UI update happens.

So the question is – what needs to be done to cause the UI to update when the `MyObject` class's property changes? I've attempted to make `MyObject` an `ObservableObject` and throw in some `didchange.send()` instructions but all without success (I believe these are redundant now in any case).

Could anyone tell me if this is possible, and how the code below should be altered to enable this? And if anyone is tempted to ask why I don't just use a struct, the reason is because in my actual project I have already tried doing this. However I am using collections of data types which modify themselves in closures (parallel processing of each item in the collection) and other hoops to jump through. I tried re-writing them as structs but ran in to so many challenges.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    @ObservedObject var source = DataSource()

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            ForEach(0..<5)
            {i in
                HelloView(displayedString: self.source.results[i].label)
            }
            Button(action: {self.source.change()})
            {
                Text("Change me")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HelloView: View
{
    var displayedString: String

    var body: some View
    {
        Text("\(displayedString)")
    }
}

class MyObject // Works if declared as a Struct
{
    init(label: String)
    {
        self.label = label
    }

    var label: String
}

class DataSource: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var results = [MyObject](repeating: MyObject(label: "test"), count: 5)

    func change()
    {
        print("I've changed")
        results[3].label = "sooner"
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false, block: {_ in self.results[1].label = "Or later"})
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider
{
    static var previews: some View
    {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `MyObject` is a class type the `results` contains references, so when you change property of any instance inside `results` the reference of that instance is not changed, so `results` is not changed, so nothing published and UI is not updated.

In such case the solution is to force publish explicitly when you perform any change of internal model

```
class DataSource: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var results = [MyObject](repeating: MyObject(label: "test"), count: 5)

    func change()
    {
        print("I've changed")
        results[3].label = "sooner"
        self.objectWillChange.send()    // << here !!

        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) {[weak self] _ in
            self?.results[1].label = "Or later"
            self?.objectWillChange.send()            // << here !!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I had been trying didChange.send() without success but looks like I hadn't kept up with the current syntax.

Comment: For anyone recreating my code, it is worth noting that in the class version, you will need to change the creation of the results array not to use the repeating initialiser – all objects in the array will point to the same instance!