# Swiftui view not getting updated when internal model class property changes

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
   @Published var players: [Player] = []
}

struct PlayerListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        List(model.players, id: \.score) { player in
            HStack {
                Text("Name: \(player.name)")
                Text("Score: \(player.score)")
                Text("Status: \(player.status)")
                Text("Salary: \(player.salary)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Player: Codable {
   let name: String
   let score: Int
   let salary: Int
   let status: String
}
```

so the problem is, if I am performing any operation that increase or decrease the count of players array then view is getting refreshed as expected, but
when something internal gets changed like Name, score or any thing by some operations like api calls view is not getting refreshed
can anyone please help me out

these solutions are not working in ios14 or above
self.objectWillChange.send()

Comment: "when something internal gets changed like name" How would that ever happen if `name` is `let`?

Comment: it is used as response model for api call

Comment: try using: `struct Players: Codable {
   var name: String
   // var ....
}`  Note the `var` and the `struct` not `Struct`

Comment: My guess would be that you are dealing with multiple sources of truth but you haven’t included relevant code to your issue.

Comment: @loremipsum, the problem is in big project but the situation is same

Comment: Look into Dependency Injection, large projects are fine but you need architecture that works well with SwiftUI it all about the basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Score isn't unique enough to be a `ForEach` id so change it to:

```
struct Player: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() // or var id: String { name } if you enforce unique names.
```

And

```
List(model.players) { player in
```

Comment: no that is not the situation actually internal changes not refreshing the ui

Comment: Internal changes should work, e.g.a change to player will be detected as a change to the array and published should send `objectWillChange` which causes `@ObservedObject` to call body. Do you have anything else in your Player struct that might be breaking the check for a difference in Player equality?

Comment: No when the count is getting increased or decreased it is getting detected and refresh the ui but when the count is same and lets say player salary got changed it is not refreshing the ui

Comment: Are you doing model.players[0].salary = 50 ? You need to be careful with struct values

Comment: no i m calling change status api which changes to status, but when status got changed ui is not getting refreshed, for refreshing the ui i need to clear array first then i again need to call to get players api which refresh the ui
same issue is here as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461199/how-to-prod-a-swiftui-view-to-update-when-a-model-class-sub-property-changes

Comment: In that other question the problem is their model is a class instead of a struct. In your example you are correctly using a struct.

Comment: yes, but i m facing same issue